# Unity photon View

Tags: unity-game-engine

so i am am using photon for my first unity game online, but i already have a problem. My caracter script for movement is working well, the sync is good etc.. But, when i try to perform a camera fixed to the player, it follow it but the second player look like he is moving (however the transform position is not moving).
Here is my PlayerInitializer script, that i used for spawn my player and attach the camera :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Camera mainCamera;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreatePlayer());
    }

    IEnumerator CreatePlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Creation du joueur");
        GameObject MyPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PhotonPlayer"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        mainCamera.GetComponent<Following_Camera>().player = MyPlayer.transform;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Here is the PlayerMovement script (a basic one):

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    Vector2 movement;
    PhotonView view;
    private void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (view.IsMine)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

And then my camera Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Following_Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector3(0,0,-10);

    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset ;
    }
}
```

[Video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2e97-ckhRc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: private video, can't access

Comment: It is on i think

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so if someone have the same problem, be aware if you where ising 3D object to do your tests. The problem was that i was using a 3D box in font, so the 2D movement where like i was watching the other sprite by his side. This is why the transform was not changing but the view was.

Answer (score -1):

Z could be changing in

```
  player.transform.position
```

Perhaps

```
transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, -10)
```

would be enough to make the camera stop circling around

Comment: The problem seems to be the same, but i was thinking that maybe it could be the the animator sprite that chance of position. However the gameObject is not moving.

Comment: Huh, one question, are you sure that the z component is the one facing up? Usually it's the y axis facing up, meaning movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); would rather be movement.z, so you would keep Y constant and move via X and Z